# Comparing an element of an array to an integer

Tags: java, arrays

Here is my assignment:
create an array of N random integers in the range of 1 to 100 (you can use the Java random class for this).  Get the value of N from the user.  Next ask the user to input a number in this range (1 to 100) and then search the array to locate all occurrences of the search number.  For each occurrence, print out the number and the position at which it was found.
Then sort the array and search again, displaying all occurrences of the search number.   If the search number is not found, then display a message to that effect.

### Finally, print the sum of all of the numbers in the array.

I cannot figure out to how compare elements of the array to an integer. Please help! Here is what I have so far

```
public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int num;
    int searchNum;
    int position = 0;
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many random integers you want to create in range (1, 100)");
    num = in.nextInt();
    int[] myList = new int[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int j = r.nextInt(101);
        myList[i] = j;
    }

    System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-100 to search");
    searchNum = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (searchNum == myList[i])
        {
            System.out.println(searchNum + " found at location: " + (position+1));
        }
        else 
        {
            position += 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: apart from the fact that you are using `position` when you should be using `i`, I don't what is not working here?

Comment: If you don't know how to compare an integer to an element of an array, then what is `if (searchNum == myList[i])` doing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it "do my homework for me" type of question.

Comment: `r.nextInt(101)` will yield a number in the range [0, 100], which isn't quite what you want.

Comment: "I don't know how to compare elements of the array to an integer" `if (searchNum == myList[i])` is doing exactly that. I don't see what else there is to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-100 to search");
searchNum = in.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    if (searchNum == myList[i])
        System.out.println(searchNum + " found at location: " + (i+1));
```

Comment: "to locate all occurrences of the search number"... you're using `break`..

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

You was nearly done, I believe.

```
public class Array {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many random integers you want to create in range (1, 100)");
    final int num = in.nextInt();

    int[] myList = new int[num];
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        myList[i] = r.nextInt(101);
    }

    System.out.println("Enter a number from 1-100 to search");

    final int searchNum = in.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (searchNum == myList[i])
        {
            System.out.println(searchNum + " found at location: " + i);
        }
    }

    Arrays.sort(myList);

    boolean any = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (searchNum == myList[i])
        {
            System.out.println(searchNum + " found ");
            any = true;
        }
        else if (searchNum > myList[i])
        {
            break;
        }       
    }

    if (!any)
    {
        System.out.println("the search number is not found");
    }
}
}
```